# CORS issue: Angular 5 on AWS S3 & Cloudfront and .net core webapi on IIS10 EC 2 windows server 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, cors, angular5, amazon-cloudfront

I am getting following error while accessing Angular app through browser (chrome/Edge/Firefox/Opera). ***API request works on direct calls from well through Postman/Fiddler.***

So i think there something between Cloudfront and EC2 calls and CORS policy

[image]

[image]

Following is my set up.

***Angular Setup:***

- S3 Bucket with Public access Policy
- Cloudfront with Behavior whitelisting Headers

[image]

***.netcore web api setup:***

- EC 2 instance with Windows Server 2019
- IIS 10 website with following httpresponse headers added  SSL implemented
  [image]
- As required I have addred CORS policy in .net core application as follows

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

added CORS middleware

```
     app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
```

Have added required Annotation over **APi Controllers**

```
     [EnableCors("EnableCORS")]
```

Not sure what am i missing along this setup.

Comment: Can you do a `options` call to your api from postman and post the results

Comment: got 405 method not allowed....response with as all required CORS Headers...Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true     Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *     Access-Control-Allow-Methods = GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, PATCH, OPTIONS      Access-Control-Allow-Headers = Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: sorry i don't follow you. can you explain what did you do and what was the result in detail.

Comment: i made a Options method request with URI  
 -https://xxx.xx.xx/api/resource/forsearch- got status code 405 method not allowed and response headrs as i mentioned above. not possible to upload screen shot in comment

Comment: are you able to do a curl request

Comment: Make sure your app is not throwing any exceptions. Exception middleware clears CORS headers (and others)

Comment: @ArunK ...i havent tried Curl....will give it a go and confimr.

Comment: @Tseng ....I have checked for no errors...as i mentioned API calls are working completely fine with postman (Except OPTIONS call...giving me 405)...

Comment: Only browsers does cross origin check. Postman and curl apps don't do, hence it's working there

Comment: can you do a curl request with an origin header, you will receive `cannot options` error if you dont have options `curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose http://localhost:3000`

Comment: in curl as well i am getting 403 forbidden. Looks like no api calls are going through as even Get calls are returning 403 forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it worked with few changes to my setup of CORS in .netcore code and IIS. Following are the changes.

- Upgraded my app from .netcore 2.2 to 3.0
- I changed CORS Origion policy from `AllowAnyOrigion()` to `WithOrigins("https://xxx.xxxx.com")`
- Removed IIS CORS module from IIS 10 web site.
- Removed All CORS headers from IIS HTTP Response Headers

to sum it up instead of trying to manage CORS headers from IIS, I left it to Kestral.

Still not sure what was the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your api is configured to send the CORS headers.

But it doesn't look like your API is configured to handle HTTP OPTIONS Verb requests. The browser sends prelight requests by sending an OPTIONS request.

The reason why i am saying that is, because you received 405 Method not allowed when you did an OPTIONS request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure how to approach to handle HTTP Options in .net core .... may be able to give me some pointers?

Comment: sorry, I am not a dot.net guy. so i dont know

Comment: I am interested to learn dot.net core, do you have any basic tutorial. Do I need vscode or visual studio

Comment: You would need VSCode for most of your earlier learning ...then you can move to Visual studio  Community edition...there are plenty of tutorials around the web. ping me at sarjandesai@live.com ... i shall forward you more details. as cant discuss in details here as it will be off the topic. thanks.